# LinkText is not fetching data from UL UI with angularjs

Tags: java, angularjs, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Click event is not working in selenium webdriver for UL LI tag with angularjs

```
package automation.test;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions;
import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.SendKeysAction;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;
import com.sun.xml.internal.txw2.Document;
public class Test {
   public static void main(String[] args) {     
    System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","../geckodriver.exe");
    DesiredCapabilities capabilities=DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
    capabilities.setCapability("marionette", true);
    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(capabilities);
    String baseUrl = "http://abc/abc/Admin"; 
    driver.get(baseUrl);
    driver.findElement(By.id("btnLogin")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.linkText("LogOut")).click();             
    driver.close();
  }
}
```

My HTML is

```
<a class="dropdown-toggle" href="/abc/Admin/Login/LogOut">LogOut </a>
```

Showing Error Like.

> "Exception in thread "main"
>   org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element:
>   LogOut"

How to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Introduce WebDriverWait to wait for the element to load.

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,30);
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.linkText("LogOut "))).click();
```

Comment: It's not working
Showing Error like 
"Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: LogOut "

Comment: As @Guy suggest , try "partialLinkText" instead of "linkText" locator and let us know the result.

Comment: WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,30);
       wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.partialLinkText("LogOut"))).click();

It's working but when i try with "Rough Transaction" Insted of LogOut it is not working.

Comment: WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,30);
       wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.partialLinkText("Rough Transactions"))).click();

Its not working.

Comment: Try "Rough Transactions" with different type of locator like cssSelector or xpath.

Comment: It is not working showing error like 
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: Transaction (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 10 milliseconds

Answer (score 0):

There are blanks in the text, try using `partialLinkText`

```
driver.findElement(By.partialLinkText("LogOut")).click();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one using css selector

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("a[href='/abc/Admin/Login/LogOut']")).click()
```